# JQuery Filtering Table with Search Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

I have 2 dropdowns that filter a table. These work properly. They show/hide rows based on the selection. I also want to add a search to further filter the rows, but I cannot get this to work.

For Example
The search needs to take into account the dropdown selections. So if dropdown 1='Three' and dropdown 2='Four' (for instance) - 5 rows are returned. If I start typing in the search box 'Right' then 2 rows should appear. When I back out of the search, then the 5 rows should reappear(dropdown filters intact)

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/rblanc/pen/eYOEgXg

Here is the JQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('#archive, #type').change(function() {
    filterTable($('#archive').val(), $('#type').val());
  });
});

function filterTable(archive, entry) {
  var $rows = $('#filter tbody tr').show();

   if (archive == "one") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('Two'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('Three'))").hide()
  } else if (archive == "two") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('One'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('Three'))").hide()
  } else if (archive == "three") {
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('One'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(4):contains('Two'))").hide()
  }

  if (entry == "one") {

    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(6):contains('N'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(7):contains('Y'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(8):contains('Y'))").hide()

  } else if (entry == "two") {

    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(6):contains('Y'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(7):contains('Y'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(8):contains('N'))").hide()

  } else if (entry == "three") {

    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(6):contains('Y'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(7):contains('N'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(8):contains('Y'))").hide()

   } else if (entry == "four") {

    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(6):contains('N'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(7):contains('Y'))").hide()
    $rows.filter(":has(td:nth-child(8):contains('N'))").hide()

   }
}

// SEARCH INPUT
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```